# Do Google Cloud SQL officially support mysqldump protocol?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Currently, I can run mysqldump from a client machine(not App engine) to connect to Google Cloud SQL instance by running this command:

```
mysqldump --host={GOOGLE_CLOUD_SQL_IP} --user={GOOGLE_CLOUD_SQL_USERNAME} --password={GOOGLE_CLOUD_SQL_PASSWORD} {DB_NAME} {TABLE_NAME} > /tmp/dump.sql
```

I can dump the content to my output file. However, my concern is this is not officially stated in [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting). So not sure does Google not endorse this and will it be dropped in the future?

Answer (score 3):

mysqldump uses the same protocol as any other mysql client. If they drop support for that, they will completely disable Google Cloud SQL.

No application or client would be able to connect.

On the brighter side, that would be very secure! :-)

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's not explicitly listed in the documentation because it's a basic feature that any MySQL host is expected to support. It would be very unusual for a host to go out of their way to not support it.